# mapcat arity error when using anonymous function macro

Tags: clojure

Why does this work:

```
(mapcat (fn [x] x) [[1] [2 3] [[4 5 6]]])
```

But this results in an arity error?

```
(mapcat #(%) [[1] [2 3] [[4 5 6]]])
```

The error is:

> ArityException Wrong number of args (0) passed to: PersistentVector  clojure.lang.AFn.throwArity (AFn.java:429)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`#(%)` is equivalent to `(fn [x] (x))` and not `(fn [x] x)`. This is the core of the problem. Whenever you're not sure what a particular piece of reader syntax does, `read-string` comes in extremely handy. Try `(read-string "#(%)")` in your REPL. It should print something like `(fn* [p1__3#] (p1__3#))`. The `p1__3#` is a free-variable, in the sense that we can replace it with any other unqualified symbol, and it would be equivalent.

As far as the `ArityException` is concerned, vectors can be called as functions. They are functions of they indices. `([:a :b :c] 1)` returns `:b`, for example. When called as functions, only arity-1 is legit. In this case `mapcat`ting with `#(%)` calls each of the vectors in your input without any arguments. This is what causes the `ArityException`.

Also, `(mapcat (fn [x] x) ...)` is the same as `(mapcat identity ...)` is the same as `(apply concat ...)`. You might want to use this instead.

Comment: `(into [] cat ...)` may also be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for:

```
(mapcat #(identity %) [[1] [2 3] [[4 5 6]]])
```

This shows the progression:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test) )

(dotest
  (let [data [[1]
              [2 3]
              [[4 5 6]]]]
    (is= [1 2 3 [4 5 6]]
      (mapcat (fn [x] x) data)
      (mapcat (fn [x] (identity x)) data)
      (mapcat #(identity %) data))))
```

When you use `#(%)` you are essentially saying:

```
([2])     ; missing arg
```

Here is how to understand it

```
(dotest
  (let [data [0 1 2 3 4]]
    (is= 2 (get data 2))
    (is= 2 (data 2))
    (is= 2 ([0 1 2 3 4] 2))
    (throws? ([0 1 2 3 4]))))
```

---

In clojure, seeing parantheses like `(xxxxx)` means "function call".  Just like in Java, seeing `xxxxx()` means "function call".  Parens in Clojure ***never mean*** grouping (I know, it is a hard habit to get out of!).

A demo:

```
(dotest
  (let [the-answer-fn (fn [& args] 42)
        fn-identity   (fn [x] x)
        fn-caller     (fn [x] (x))]
    (is= 42 (the-answer-fn))
    (is= 3 (identity 3))
    (is= 3 (fn-identity 3))
    (is= 42 (fn-caller the-answer-fn))
    (is (fn? #(the-answer-fn))) ; it always returns a function
    (throws? (fn-caller 3))))
```

---

Note that the `#(xxx)` reader macro is just a shorthand notation for

```
(fn [] (xxx))
```

So, it invokes it's body.  As a memory aid, just pretend the `#` isn't there.  The remaining part shows what happens.

Also, remember that you are returning a new function that wraps the `(xxx)` function call.

Comment: Why? Isn't #(%) an identity function?

Comment: Hmm. This sent me down the road to realize that #(%) != (fn [x] x). Specifically (#(%) 3) throws a cast exception, but ((fn [x] x) 3) does not. It appears that the #() macro will invoke it's body, where fn will not.

Comment: See update to answer.

Comment: @AlanThompson You've surely been on Stack Overflow for long enough to have seen this question asked before; or if not, to guess that it has been asked before. When a duplicate question is asked, prefer to spend a few moments finding the best duplicate, and close the new question pointing to the older one. It's better to make it easy to find the existing high-quality answers than to have answers scattered across the site.